# How use lookupvalue with text

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am using powerbi and I have two different datas, a1 and a2, as in the tables below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81ARC.png)

I tried add the column New using the code below, but it does not work

```
New = LOOKUPVALUE (a1[value],a1[date],a2[date]),a1[country],a2[country],a1[type],"new")
```

the following error message appears:

The name 'LOOKUPVALUE' wasn't recognized. Make sure it's spelled correctly.
How can I fix it?

the end result would be this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI5Si.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a single table with those 3 columns I would do the following:

1. Append the a2 table under the a1 table. Then pivot the type and value column so that each country and date pair will have a old, new and valueA column.

If you make a new query and paste this into the advanced editor it will create table A2 (Make sure to name this query A2):

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WKkgtKlXSUTLUNdQ1MjAyBjJNgABIORopxeogyRuB5I2ATAsDAwMs8sYweUvs8ibY9YcGO6JabwoEmNJw2w2NsGqH226GVRphuYUlVDYWAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [country = _t, date = _t, value = _t, #"type" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"country", type text}, {"date", type date}, {"value", Int64.Type}, {"type", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Then you will need to make a second query and paste the following:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WKkgtKlXSUTLUNdQ1MjAyBjLzc1KApKmBgYFSrA6SAiOQAiO4AhMMBcaoCiwwFJigKjDGUAB3Q15qOUgAtxsgCjCtMEZVYIrTCRB5S5gBocGO2ELBBF0eLRDM0OXRwsAcXR4tCIxw2g93Pw770QIAw34c/kPzP8R/sQA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [country = _t, date = _t, #"type" = _t, value = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"country", type text}, {"date", type date}, {"type", type text}, {"value", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({#"Changed Type", A2}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Appended Query", List.Distinct(#"Appended Query"[#"type"]), "type", "value", List.Sum)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

This will result in the following table:

[image: Result Table]

[image: Advanced Editor]